# SP2010 Foundation SPServices Jquery Cascaded dropdown

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I'm new to SharePoint dev and i've implemented SPServices Cascaded dropdown using Jquery.

I managed to get it to work in a subsite of the top level site collection, without problems.
But the problem is that i've got some lists and a lib on the top level site collection and i want to implement the Cascaded dropdown there also. And that won't work, i've checked if the scripts are fully loaded with following code;

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" src="//sharepoint/Style%20Library/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="//sharepoint/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {

alert("jquery");
alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
});
</script>
```

And indeed, it gives me the two pop-ups, so there's no problem.

But when i render the following code;

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" src="">http://sharepoint/SPServices/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script>
<script language="javascript" src="">http://sharepoint/SPServices/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js</script>
<script language="javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "lookupCountry",
relationshipListParentColumn: "Region",
relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
parentColumn: "Region",
childColumn: "Country",
debug: true
});

});
</script>
```

Nothing happens...not even an error.

I've checked the blog of Marc D Anderson, and read the documentation of the SPServices and so many others, but without success.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
  relationshipWebURL: "",
  relationshipList: "",
  relationshipListParentColumn: "",
  relationshipListChildColumn: "",
  relationshipListSortColumn: "",
  parentColumn: "",
  childColumn: "",
  CAMLQuery: "",
  CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns></QueryOptions>", // Added in 2013.01
  listName: $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl(), 
  promptText: "",
  simpleChild: false,           // Added in v0.6.2
  selectSingleOption: false,        // Added in v0.6.2
  matchOnId: false,         // Added in v0.7.1
  completefunc: null,
  debug: false
});
```

You should use the **relationshipWebURL** parameter, if the relation is not on the current web site.

> **relationshipWebURL** The URL of the Web (site) which contains the relationshipList. If not specified, the current site is used. Examples
>   would be: "/", "/Accounting", "/Departments/HR", etc. Note: It's
>   always best to use relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in 2013.01 when used in the root site of the Web App. Try 0.7.2 for now. I've got a new release (2013.02) coming soon with the fix.

[Update]

You can also continue to use 2013.01 but pass in the webURL for the root site even though it is the current site, e.g.,

relationshipWebURL: "/"

[/Update]